# Printer won't stop printing

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, hp-laserjet

I have an HP LaserJet P2035N connected to my home network.  I have it set up as a printer on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.  Windows found the printer on the network and installed a driver itself.

However, when I print, it continues to print copy after copy of any job that I send it.  To stop the printing, I have to open the print spool and delete the job - is the printer supposed to be handling the queue deletion? Any ideas what would cause this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Ports tab of the Printer Properties window, I unchecked "Enable bidirectional support" and it started operating normally.

Comment: This worked for me, too. 32-bit Windows 7, with an HP LaserJet p1606dn connected over the network.

Comment: Same here, 64bits W10 pro ... It's the windows driver f*cked up.